# Use Map Data Type with Compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am using Compass with Sass (v 3.3 Maptastic Maple) and I am trying to use the new maps data structure. I am using grunt watch with compass, however when using the new maps syntax, it throws an error everytime I run grunt.

```
$colors: (
  header: #b06,
  text: #334,
  footer: #666777
);
```

This is the error:

```
error sass/main.scss (Line 73 of sass/base/_variables.scss: Invalid CSS after "  header": expected ")", was ": #b06,")
```

How can I use the new sass maps with compass?

Comment: This is valid scss, are you sure Grunt is using the correct version of Sass?  Which version of Compass are you using (the current stable version is incompatible with Sass 3.3)?

Comment: I am using "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.7.2"

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get compass to compile the new syntax by installing the alpha of the latest version.

```
gem install compass --pre
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with you, and after few hours of trying and googling, I found 2 solutions:

1. If you can, use grunt-contrib-sass instead.
2. But if you need to use grunt-contrib-compass, check the answer at this one [Is Sass 3.3 compatible with Compass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427567/is-sass-3-3-3-compatible-with-compass)