# PhpStorm 8 + compass + sass + susy + breakpoint to work altogether

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

I'm trying to switch to PhpStorm 8 and everything seems to be working fine except one thing. 
While converting sass file with next code

```
.know{
    margin-top: 30px;
    &-item {
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        transition: all 500ms ease;
        &_style {...
```

it's giving me error

```
error style.scss (Line 199: Invalid CSS after " &": expected "{", was "-item {"
"-item" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.)
```

I know this was a problem before SASS version 3.3 but in my terminal I checked the version and its

```
Sass 3.3.7 (Maptastic Maple)
```

So the question is: does PhpStorm uses it's own SASS file?
When I check SASS version inseв PhpStorm version is N/A!

[image]

Comment: And ..? **"SASS support" plugin has NOTHING to do with compilation** -- it is for editor only (syntax highlighting/check etc). Compilation is done with whatever you have installed on your system. If you are compiling SASS inside IDE (using File Watcher plugin) make sure that it uses correct version (in case if you have more than one on your system)

Comment: @ LazyOne I see, thanks for explanation. Now I see the problem. After I uninstaled compass and sass, I installed the lateste sass-3.3.14. But after I've installed Compass it also included old sass-3.2.19! After removing sass-3.2.19 manually PHPstorm says Compass: Failed to run compass!

Comment: Cannot really help here -- not a Compass user so cannot give you any *specific* advice on what can be done here. But in any case: does it work outside / in terminal? If it does not -- fix it somehow (maybe re-configuring Compass / downloading newer version?). If it works -- lets dig deeper.

Comment: Here's a better match:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427567/is-sass-3-3-3-compatible-with-compass

Comment: @cimmanon - thanks for your input, but it looks more like a hack and not a solution.

Comment: How is this a hack?  Compass 0.12 (latest stable) is not compatible with Sass 3.3.  If you're running Compass 0.12, it will always use Sass 3.2 (which does not have support for any of the 3.3 features like the BEM syntax you're trying to use).  If you want to use Sass 3.3, you need to use Compass 1.0 (currently still alpha).

Comment: @cimmanon - well, I guess installing a DevKit and WDM is not a clean  way to solve the problem. For me, working with sublime or coda + fireapp doesnt bring any headache. I just wanted to start using a serious IDE and at the moment I already spent to much time setting up the things which doesn't work together ((

Comment: Those shouldn't be necessary.  Just upgrade to Compass 1.0.

Comment: @cimmanon - ok, I managed to solve the problem. First of all thanks for pointing to compass version, as it was the main reason. But to solve the issues in a complex (compass+sass+susy+breakpoint) I had to use bundler. thanks again ))